# Counting the number of threads posted in a Drupal Forum Using Drupal API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-ajax

I am New to Drupal Apis and i am now looking to build a few analytics board for our Drupal Forums.

I am looking to fetch the following data, so that i can use it generate weekly reports.

Total no of threads in a specific forum.

Total number of posts(responses) for The threads above, so that i can calculate responses by people in different groups(mods,Admins etc)

I am trying to find if i could fetch the above data using any of the Drupal API REST calls. Can anybody suggest me what would be the best approach to fetch this data, as this involves  a simple read-only calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print user_stats_get_stats('post_count', $uid);
```

Will print post count for a node by user

To group them by (mods,Admins etc) you need to fetch all uids from bd and it can simply done with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: Nikhil,

Thanks for your answer. I am developing a different application which leverages the Drupal API to fetch this data. Can you point mw to some docs which help me to fetch this data using the function user_stats_get_stats programatically?